# Dynamic Page creation tkinter

Tags: user-interface, tkinter, python-3.4

I am following an example of Python code at this [link](https://pythonprogramming.net/change-show-new-frame-tkinter/). My ultimate goal is to try to create a dynamic number of pages using a database query. The query would return a list of items and I could create a dictionary entry instantiating each one as a page.

I attempted to create that here by creating a Page class which is instantiated in the dictionary with just a list of numbers, however I can't seem to get the StartPage showing, all that shows up is one of the Page pages. My source code:

```
class SeaofBTCapp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        container = tk.Frame(self)

        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)

        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}

        database_pages = [1, 2, 3, 4]

        count = 0
        for p in database_pages:
            page_num = p
            frame = Page(container, self)
            self.frames[page_num] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
            count += 1

        self.frames[count] = StartPage(container, self)
        self.show_frame(count)

    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()

class Page(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        label = tk.Label(self, text="label for Page")
        label.pack()
```

I tried adding it as a dictionary entry and calling that key. I get no errors, but the StartPage isn't visible. How can I show StartPage at the start? Is there a better way to achieve this?

**EDIT**

As suggested, I changed:

```
    self.frames[count] = StartPage(container, self)
    self.show_frame(count)
```

to:

```
    frame = StartPage(container, self)
    self.frames[count + 1] = frame
    frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nsew')
    self.show_frame(count + 1)
```

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't call `grid` after creating `StartPage`, so it will be invisible. Add the following after you create `StartPage`:

```
start.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
```

You have another problem in that you are putting `StartPage` at index 4, but you already have a frame at index 4. That's not contributing to the problem in this question, but it will cause problems when you try to see the other page.

Comment: Thanks! wow, I can't believe I didn't catch that. Just to be clear the command that was missing was container.pack() at the bottom of the first class.

Comment: @BenC: I don't understand your comment. Your code already calls `pack` on the container.  There's no missing `pack` command in your code.

Comment: Sorry, I jumped ahead of myself. it wasn't container.pack. I made the code under the for loop include the startpage to the grid. Ill update my post.